# Get Number of Open issues from GitHub using GitHub API

Tags: php, api, curl, github, github-api

I am developing a php application where user input a link to any public GitHub repository and output will be

(i) Total number of open issues

(ii) Number of open issues that were opened in the last 24 hours

(iii) Number of open issues that were opened more than 24 hours ago but less than 7 days ago

(iv) Number of open issues that were opened more than 7 days ago

Code for printing the **(i) Total number of open issues** is given below using the github api and php curl and it is working fine.
But I have no idea how to print the other above three points **(ii),(iii) and (iv)**.
Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//Test url
$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/anandkgpt03/test";
//Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
//Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//Set the User Agent as username
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "anandkgpt03");
//Accept the response as json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept: application/json'));
//Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

//Decode the json in associative array
$new_result=json_decode($result,true);

echo "Total Number of Open Issues:".$new_result["open_issues_count"];
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please provide a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)? Any program that would consume the API over HTTP could do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan for guiding me. So I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks @AlanFluka, GitHub API really proved helpful.So I have used curl in php to consume the API over HTTP.

Comment: If you found a solution that worked, you can post it as an answer and also accept your own answer. This helps SO to become a knowledge database and not a heap of unanswered questions.

Comment: But the solution is incomplete. As my question have 4 parts and I have found the solution of only 1 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **since** paramater available in GitHub API that return only issues updated at or after this time that helps in getting number of open issues opened after any time.

This url can be helpful to read more about it: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

Below is the proper working code of my question.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Full URL of GitHub repository" size="60">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    //Example-> https://github.com/Shippable/support/issues
    $input_url = $_POST['url'];
    //Break the input url in array format
    $input_url_array =  explode('/',$input_url);

    //Validate the input url
    if(strcmp($input_url_array[0],"https:")||strcmp($input_url_array[1],"")||strcmp($input_url_array[2],"github.com")||empty($input_url_array[3])||empty($input_url_array[4]))
    {
        die("</br>Invalid Url !!! Url should be in format <b>https://github.com/{org_name or username}/{repo_name}/</b><br>");
    }

    //url for the github Api, $input_url_array[3] contain organisation or username, put_url_array[3] contain repository name
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/".$input_url_array[3]."/".$input_url_array[4];
    //call the function and receive the result in associative array format
    $result = curlRequestOnGitApi($url);
    //Get total no of open issues using the $result array
    $total_open_issues = $result["open_issues_count"];
    echo "<br>Total Open Issues:<b>".$total_open_issues."</b><br>";


    //Date and Time 1 day or 24 hours ago in ISO 8601 Format
    $time_last24hr = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z', strtotime('-1 day', time()));
    //url for the github Api with since parameter equal to time of last 24 hrs that return only issues updated at or after this time 
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/".$input_url_array[3]."/".$input_url_array[4]."/issues?since=".$time_last24hr;     
    //call the function and receive the result in associative array format
    $result = curlRequestOnGitApi($url);
    //Get no of open issues that were opened in last 24 hours
    $issues_last24hr = count($result);
    echo "Number of open issues that were opened in the last 24 hours:<b>".$issues_last24hr."</b><br>";


    //Date and Time 1 day or 24 hours ago in ISO 8601 Format
    $time_7daysago = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z', strtotime('-7 day', time()));
    //url for the github Api with since parameter equal to time of 7 days ago that return only issues updated at or after this time 
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/".$input_url_array[3]."/".$input_url_array[4]."/issues?since=".$time_7daysago;
    //call the function and receive the result in associative array format
    $result = curlRequestOnGitApi($url);
    //Get no of open issues that were opened in 7 days ago
    $issues_last7days = count($result);
    echo "Number of open issues that were opened more than 24 hours ago but less than 7 days ago:<b>".($issues_last7days-$issues_last24hr)."</b><br>";


    echo "Number of open issues that were opened more than 7 days ago:<b>".($total_open_issues-$issues_last7days)."</b><br>";
}       

function curlRequestOnGitApi($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    //Set the User Agent as username
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "anyusername");

    //Accept the response as json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept: application/json'));

    //Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);

    //Decode the json in array
    $new_result=json_decode($result,true);

    //Return array
    return $new_result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by using the GitHub API.

Follow these steps:

1. Visit the issues url with the option `state open`:
   `https://api.github.com/repos/{name}/support/issues?q=state:open`.
2. In the results (in JSON format) look for the `created_at` timestamp.
3. Compare the aforementioned values with the current timestamp and sort these outputs by using any datetime function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @varocarbas from what I gathered, the "url" in question is an example of calling the API method. Better formatting would make that clear, though. I'd do it, but it's not really a substantial edit, and I have no knowledge of curl to make it one by providing a code example.

Comment: @AlanFluka My comment above (clarification: not written by me, but by the reviewing system when I chose the "this is a link-based answer" option) is quite clear: this is not what a SO answer is expected to consist in; no matter how accurate and helpful the given link is. You can either post it as a comment or write here the basic ideas by your own. External links might fail in the future. Additionally, SO is not expected to be a collection of external references, but an independent source of knowledge created by its members (who might have learned in other sites).

Comment: @AlanFluka Just in case this idea isn't clear to you: this answer was flagged by someone as low quality and included in the corresponding queue for reviewers. Reviewers (= users with higher rep) vote to delete all these listed questions and they might add a comment or not. I decided to add a comment (the one above, written automatically by the system), but might have voted without saying anything (what other reviewers can also do). In summary: even in case that you would be right, I am not the only person to convince. Just bear in mind that we all try to make SO better.

Comment: @varocarbas Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I meant is the "link" was never meant to be clicked, but only shown as a code example of calling the API function (like `-https://api.github.com/repos/{name}/support/issues?q=state:open`). In fact, the standard SO link formatting was never used, it was written as plain text. If the GitHub API ever changes, then yes the example would become incorrect, but so would any other answer related to questions about the API.

Comment: @varocarbas thanks for clearing out how SO works to me, though. I just commented on something that seemed to me as a simple oversight.

Comment: @AlanFluka OK. Sorry about the misunderstanding. I have editted the answer to transmit the ideas clearly. I will trust in your opinion (+ Indu1 one) and assume that this is right (never tested it) and will +1 it. In any case, note that it is in the low-quality queue with some votes so it might be deleted anyway. In the future, make an effort to transmit the ideas properly; bear in mind that there are lots of posts to be reviewed (and we cannot always spend too much time on each of them). Additionally, this is not exactly a programming-related answer but if it might be acceptable.